# как сделать отправку файла из памяти?

Tags: c#, upload

Хочу сделать отправку txt файла на свой сайт(предварительно сам сайт сохраняет файл в директорию).
То есть через память задаём текст в txt(но не сохраняем файл в системе) и отправляет файл

```
            byte[] bytes = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    tw.Write("blabla");
                    tw.Flush();
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    bytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Сама функцию отправки

```
                try
                {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    client.UploadFile("http://server.ru/index.php", "POST", file);

                    client.Dispose();

                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
```

Comment: И что, этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли? Какой тип приложения, какая версия дотнета, откуда вызвается этот код? Данную операцию можно провести с помощью асинхронного кода и `HttpClient`, но нужно знать детали, как этот код вызывается, кнопка там у вас или основной какой-то метод, вы скрыли код, позволяющий это понять.

Comment: Что за сервер, он принимает `multipart/form-data` POST? У вас есть форма отправки файла на веб-странице, какой запрос она отправляет в браузере. Покажите заголовки этого POST запроса.